# adding a method to a php class

Tags: php, mysqli

am new at OOP, I have a mysqli class wrapper for my database. There are methods that are not in the wrapper and i want to use them in my queries, i just don't know how to add them in the class.

My class is here  https://bitbucket.org/getvivekv/php-mysqli-class/src/f72d10285e9327681109871dccd99e23891bfde9/class.database.php?at=master

i need to count the number of rows of a select statement.

**Here is what am doing**

```
 $where = array(
     'staff_id' => 'Input::get("staff_id")',
     'role' => 'Input::get("role")'
    );
$sel = $db->select()->from('staff_role')->where($where) ;

 $total = mysqli_num_rows($sel);

if($total==0){

}
```

**I get this warning**

```
Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result.
```

Any help please

Comment: Your $sel isn't loaded with a result set from the query something is going wrong there. Print_r($sel) to see what it contains and else revise your query and code surrounding the query.

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

1) Verify these lines, do you really need quotes when you call these methods?

```
'staff_id' => 'Input::get("staff_id")',
'role' => 'Input::get("role")'
```

2) You wrapper class has a method execute() which you did not call, which should be like this

```
$sel = $db->select()->from('staff_role')->where($where)->execute();
```

Now you should get the result set. You wrapper will throw error if there is any problem in the sql statement. To get count, you have

```
$db->affected_rows
```

To get results use query() instead of execute() method.

Comment: I also recommend to add the execute function.

Comment: i have added it , then how  do i count them?